# Search Filter is not deleting my list items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I'm trying to do is when the user search for a color code its suppose to filter the colors. What's working is at total there are 13 items and when i type input it does shows how many correct filter number but color bubbles are not being removed.

What I'm trying to do is remove the bubbles also when the search happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length - 1;
  $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');


  $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    //$(this).addClass('hidden');

    var searchTerm = $("#search-text").val();
    var listItem = $('#list2').children('li');


    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

    //extends :contains to be case insensitive
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
      'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
          .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }
    });


    $("#list2 li").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in2');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.out').addClass('hidden');
      }, 300);
    });

    $("#list2 li:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in2');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.in2').removeClass('hiding');
      }, 1);
    });


    var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length - 1;
    $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');

    //shows empty state text when no jobs found
    if (jobCount == '0') {
      $('#list2').addClass('empty');
    } else {
      $('#list2').removeClass('empty');
    }

  });
});

var selector = '.color-list .color';
$(".color").css('background', function() {
  return $(this).data('color');
});

$(selector).on('click', function() {
  var colorName = $(this).data('name');
  var colorHEX = $(this).data('color');
  $(selector).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('');
  $('#options_1010_text').val(colorName);
  $('#test-bg').css('background-color', colorHEX);

});

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: rgb(33 35 38 / 50%) 0px 10px 10px -10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.colPadding {
  padding: 20px;
}

.chartTitle,
.chartTitle:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.chartViewAll,
.chartViewAll:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4 !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.yellowHues,
.yellowHues:active {
  background-color: #d7b327 !important;
}

.orangeHues,
.orangeHues:active {
  background-color: #ff7700 !important;
}

.redHues,
.redHues:active {
  background-color: #d64818 !important;
}

.violetHues,
.violetHues:active {
  background-color: #8b1892 !important;
}

.blueHues,
.blueHues:active {
  background-color: #0d2791 !important;
}

.greenHues,
.greenHues:active {
  background-color: #1e7f16 !important;
}

.greyHues,
.greyHues:active {
  background-color: #888888 !important;
}

.brownHues,
.brownHues:active {
  background-color: #6c4a11 !important;
}

.whiteAndBlackHues,
.whiteAndBlackHues:active {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
}

.block-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.color-picker {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
}

.color-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.color-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.color {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: attr(data-color);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.color:not(.active):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D7D1D5;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

.ralChartAccordionDiv {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.colorPickerCol {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ral-chart-form {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.color:not(.active) p {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.color:not(.active):hover p {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}

.ral-1000,
.ral-1001,
.ral-1002,
.ral-1003,
.ral-1004,
.ral-1005,
.ral-1006,
.ral-1007,
.ral-1011,
.ral-1012,
.ral-1013,
.ral-1014,
.ral-1015,
.ral-1016,
.ral-1017,
.ral-1018,
.ral-1019,
.ral-1020,
.ral-1021,
.ral-1023,
.ral-1024,
.ral-1026,
.ral-1027,
.ral-1028,
.ral-1032,
.ral-1033,
.ral-1034,
.ral-1035,
.ral-1036,
.ral-1037,
.ral-2000,
.ral-2001,
.ral-2002,
.ral-2003,
.ral-2004,
.ral-2005,
.ral-2007,
.ral-2008,
.ral-2009,
.ral-2010,
.ral-2011,
.ral-2012,
.ral-2013,
.ral-3000,
.ral-3001,
.ral-3002,
.ral-3003,
.ral-3004,
.ral-3005,
.ral-3007,
.ral-3009,
.ral-3011,
.ral-3012,
.ral-3013,
.ral-3014,
.ral-3015,
.ral-3016,
.ral-3017,
.ral-3018,
.ral-3020,
.ral-3022,
.ral-3024,
.ral-3026,
.ral-3027,
.ral-3027,
.ral-3028,
.ral-3031,
.ral-3032,
.ral-3033,
.ral-3000,
.ral-4001,
.ral-4002,
.ral-4003,
.ral-4004,
.ral-4005,
.ral-4006,
.ral-4007,
.ral-4008,
.ral-4009,
.ral-4010,
.ral-4011,
.ral-4012,
.ral-5000,
.ral-5001,
.ral-5002,
.ral-5003,
.ral-5004,
.ral-5005,
.ral-5007,
.ral-5008,
.ral-5009,
.ral-5010,
.ral-5011,
.ral-5012,
.ral-5013,
.ral-5014,
.ral-5015,
.ral-5017,
.ral-5018,
.ral-5019,
.ral-5020,
.ral-5021,
.ral-5022,
.ral-5023,
.ral-5024,
.ral-5025,
.ral-5026,
.ral-6000,
.ral-6001,
.ral-6002,
.ral-6003,
.ral-6004,
.ral-6005,
.ral-6006,
.ral-6007,
.ral-6008,
.ral-6009,
.ral-6010,
.ral-6011,
.ral-6012,
.ral-6013,
.ral-6014,
.ral-6015,
.ral-6016,
.ral-6017,
.ral-6018,
.ral-6019,
.ral-6020,
.ral-6021,
.ral-6022,
.ral-6024,
.ral-6025,
.ral-6026,
.ral-6027,
.ral-6028,
.ral-6029,
.ral-6032,
.ral-6033,
.ral-6034,
.ral-6035,
.ral-6036,
.ral-6037,
.ral-6038,
.ral-6032,
.ral-7000,
.ral-7001,
.ral-7002,
.ral-7003,
.ral-7004,
.ral-7005,
.ral-7006,
.ral-7008,
.ral-7009,
.ral-7010,
.ral-7011,
.ral-7012,
.ral-7013,
.ral-7015,
.ral-7016,
.ral-7021,
.ral-7022,
.ral-7023,
.ral-7024,
.ral-7026,
.ral-7030,
.ral-7031,
.ral-7032,
.ral-7033,
.ral-7034,
.ral-7035,
.ral-7036,
.ral-7037,
.ral-7038,
.ral-7039,
.ral-7040,
.ral-7042,
.ral-7043,
.ral-7044,
.ral-7045,
.ral-7046,
.ral-7047,
.ral-7048,
.ral-8000,
.ral-8001,
.ral-8002,
.ral-8003,
.ral-8004,
.ral-8007,
.ral-8008,
.ral-8011,
.ral-8012,
.ral-8014,
.ral-8015,
.ral-8016,
.ral-8017,
.ral-8019,
.ral-8022,
.ral-8023,
.ral-8024,
.ral-8025,
.ral-8028,
.ral-8029,
.ral-9001,
.ral-9002,
.ral-9003,
.ral-9004,
.ral-9005,
.ral-9006,
.ral-9007,
.ral-9010,
.ral-9011,
.ral-9016,
.ral-9017,
.ral-9018,
.ral-9022,
.ral-9023 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#list1,
#list2,
#list3,
#list4,
#list5,
#list6,
#list7,
#list8,
#list9,
#list10,
#list11,
#list12,
#list13 {
  display: contents;
}

#search-text {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #2b2b2b;
}

 ::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #2b2b2b;
}

svg.bi.bi-search {
  fill: #2b2b2b;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -55px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 428px) {
  svg.bi.bi-search {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container ralChartAccordionDiv text-center">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="SEARCH A RAL CLASSIC" class="search-box">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="list2">
  <li class="in2">
    <div class="accordion orangeHues">
      <p class="chartTitle">Orange Hues</p>
      <p class="chartViewAll">View All</p>
      <span class="list-count2"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="color-picker block-center">
        <ul class="color-list">
          <li class="color in2" data-color="#EEA205" data-name="RAL 2000">
            <p class="ral-2000">RAL 2000</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#DD7907" data-name="RAL 2001">
            <p class="ral-2001">RAL 2001</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#BE4E20" data-name="RAL 2002">
            <p class="ral-2002">RAL 2002</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#C63927" data-name="RAL 2003">
            <p class="ral-2003">RAL 2003</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#FA842B" data-name="RAL 2004">
            <p class="ral-2004">RAL 2004</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#E75B12" data-name="RAL 2005">
            <p class="ral-2005">RAL 2005</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#FF2300" data-name="RAL 2007">
            <p class="ral-2007">RAL 2007</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#FFA421" data-name="RAL 2008">
            <p class="ral-2008">RAL 2008</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#F3752C" data-name="RAL 2009">
            <p class="ral-2009">RAL 2009</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#E15501" data-name="RAL 2010">
            <p class="ral-2010">RAL 2010</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#D4652F" data-name="RAL 2011">
            <p class="ral-2011">RAL 2011</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#EC7C25" data-name="RAL 2012">
            <p class="ral-2012">RAL 2012</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#DB6A50" data-name="RAL 2013">
            <p class="ral-2013">RAL 2013</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="colPadding"></div>
```

Comment: Is  all that code necessary to demonstrate your problem? Please see [ask] and revise to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you don't have `hidden` class in your css. Add something like `.hidden { display: none !important; }`

Also, note that `$("#list2 li")` will catch and hide the wrapping `li.in2` element. Use e.g. `$("#list2 .color-list li")` instead;

Comment: Assuming that this is a Bootstrap project, `visually-hidden`  (BS5) or `sr-only` (BS4) are available.